# Datamacro can't be found after split dadatabase

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-data-macro

I have an access 2007 database with datamacros in the tables. After splitting the database because I want multiple users to work in  it they cant be found.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the backend database directly with Access. That should reveal the macros.

Comment: Hi Gustav. The front end event doesn't want to execute ( add eecords)  because it can't find the back end datamacro after I split it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The frontend will not "execute" anything because of a backend data macro.

Comment: That's correct. I have a datamacro o  a "comments" table on the back end . In a form in the front end I have a command button that is to add a record to the table and link it to the event. But when I try to press the button you execute it says it can't fi d the table datamacro.

Comment: Yes, a data macro lives with the table in the backend. The code or macro to be executed in the frontend must be created in this.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I'm not an expert so I guess I am going to have wrote a SQL macro for this ?

Comment: It might be easier to use DAO.